# Is the validation set in CV considered "out-of-sample"?

Tags: cross-validation, hyperparameter

Let's say I want to tune hyperparameter lambda in a Lasso regressor. I have a train and validation set for hyperparameter tuning using 10-fold CV. Can the MSE calculated on the 10% validation fold each time be considered an out-of-sample MSE, or is it technically more an "estimate" of the out-of-sample MSE?

Comment: Everything is an estimate. The procedure you describe sounds a lot like "nested cross validation".

Answer (score 1):

As said by Cagdas Ozgenc, what you obtain with CV is always an estimate. From your explanation It seems me that you obtain something like $MSE(\lambda)$ and at the end you have $MSE(\lambda_{best}) < MSE(\lambda)$, where $\lambda_{best}$ is the tuned parameter you looked for.
However it seems me that $MSE(\lambda_{best})$ represent a too optimistic estimate for test MSE, especially if you try with many value for  $\lambda$.